# Open specific "html" extension with a specific application

Tags: macos, operating-system, window, electron, open-with

I have built an electron application that allow user to generate and open files (let say "`foo.bar`").

For some reasons, I want user that don't have this application installed to be able to open those files, so as the application is Javascript Based, users can generate the file under "`foo.bar.html`"with the application embedded in HTML/JS.

So if anyone open the "`foo.bar.html`", they will be able to open the document.

Is it possible (I know the question is OS specific, so it might need an answer per OS, especially Windows and OSX), to make users having the Electron application to have "`*.bar.html`" files opened with the Electron application, while users without the application will see the file opened with the browser ?